# comparison of pointer and integer

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])


for (int i=1; i<argc ; i++)

{
    cout<< argv[i]<< endl;

if( argv[i] == 'all')
         cout<<"hey"<< endl;


}
```

i am passing   "1 all emptyfile" through the command files. but i want to compare when argue[i] is equal to all, i want it to print hey 
i get this error "Comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')" at the if( argv[i] == 'all') anyway i could do it ?

Comment: `’all’` has type `int`. because it’s a “multi character literal”, an obscure and not particularly useful C language feature. `”all”` is a string literal, which is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

C-style strings can't be compared directly, and even worse, `'all'` isn't a string (you probably meant `"all"`, note the quotes).

The C-way to compare them is to use `strcmp`:

```
#include <cstring>

if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "all") == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Your example matches when argv[i] differs from "all". `strcmp` returns zero for a match.

Comment: @WikkBickford I must have been drousy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, you can use `std::string` which will allow you to compare strings directly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string s = "all";
    for (int i=1; i<argc ; i++)
    {
        cout<< argv[i]<< endl;      
        if( argv[i] == s)
             cout<<"hey"<< endl;
    }
}
```

Note: `all` is in double-quotes.

Output when you run the program:

```
>a.exe all
all
hey
```